# Distance slider does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

In WinXP + FF 3.6.3 and 3.6.4, all I get is a grey box. There's nothing to drag around, just a background image.

This means that when I search, the default search radius of 20 miles is always applied. This, of course, can be corrected manually in the URL's querystring, but that's not how it's supposed to work, I assume.

[image]

**EDIT:** Is it possible this UI piece is pulling scripts from a site I've blocked? I'm running NoScript in Firefox.

**EDIT:** Okay, it's not NoScript. I disabled it, and same thing. I did a bit of testing with FireBug and it looks like a JavaScript issue.

Comment: Note also: the UI is the same regardless of what is in the "where" text box.

Comment: Are you using AdBlock perchance?

Comment: @Jason: Yes. Here are all my addons: Adblock Plus v1.1.3, Firebug 1.5.0, Greasemonkey 0.8.20100211.5, Java Console 6.0.18, Java Quick Starter 1.0, MS .NET Framework Assistant 1.0, and NoScript 1.9.9.47.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can reproduce the problem with Ad Block on our end, after a smart bit of detective work by [Jason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6212/jason-punyon).

We're running "ads" on the right-hand side, and when they are blocked, it seems to stop the execution of other stuff. I've made a change so that ads load last, which should mitigate the issue -- we'll go live with it tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, yes, if I disable AdBlock, the slider works. Good sleuthing! (Will upvote when I get more votes in 3 hours.)

Comment: This works for me now with AdBlock enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's time to upgrade your browser...

That said, it should probably have a text box or radio buttons when nifty ajaxy stuff isn't available due to a browser being old and busted.

Comment: Old and busted? FireFox 3.6.4 only came out two days ago...

Comment: I LOL'd. That being said, I upgraded to 3.6.4, and it's still broken.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: it definitely works on FF3.6.3/Win7, and Chrome5/Win7

Comment: @Grace Note: it was a joke, son!

Comment: @Randolpho: Wow. I just tried using IE6 (default install with XP), and while the layout is completely busted, the slider works perfectly. hahahaha

Comment: @Jon Seigel: either the problem is your particular setup in Firefox, or some bug in Firefox that only presents itself on WinXP. Maybe it's time to upgrade your OS.....:)

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Your ABP and Firebug are out-of-date as well.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for letting me know.